# Stripe subscriptions - how to update end date without charging customer

Tags: stripe-payments

I'm using stripe subscriptions, now I have to change an end date but I don't want to charge my customer for this upgrade.

If I update the subscription, stripe calculate the amount due and invoice it.

How can I update only the dates, without charging my customer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way to achieve this is by adding a trial period to your subscription.
What [@Nishang Raiyani](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17745239/nishang-raiyani) suggested doesn't really work and will result with this error

```
When updating an existing subscription, billing_cycle_anchor must be either unset,
'now', or 'unchanged'
```

Answer (score -1):

1. **Retrieve the Current Subscription:**
   First, use the Stripe API to get the details of your existing subscription. You'll need the subscription ID for this.

   ```js
   const currentSubscription = await stripe.subscriptions.retrieve('sub_XXXXXXXXXXXX');
   ```
2. **Update the Billing Cycle Anchor:**
   To change the end date without charging your customer, update the subscription's billing cycle anchor. This essentially sets the start date for the next billing cycle to a future date.

   ```js
   const updatedSubscription = await stripe.subscriptions.update('sub_XXXXXXXXXXXX', {
     billing_cycle_anchor: newUnixTimestamp, // Replace with the desired future timestamp
   });
   ```

   Make sure that `newUnixTimestamp` is a Unix timestamp representing the future start date of the next billing cycle.
3. **Verify the Changes:**
   Confirm that the subscription details have been updated as expected.

   ```js
   console.log(updatedSubscription);
   ```

This approach allows you to adjust the subscription dates without immediately charging the customer. Keep in mind to handle any proration or invoice adjustments that may occur due to changes in the billing cycle, and refer to the [Stripe API documentation](https://stripe.com/docs/api/subscriptions/update) for the latest details on subscription management and billing adjustments.